# Fetch and display image from API (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I Have local API which contains many objects
in every object there is one image
like this:

```
{
created_at: "2022-09-10T19:40:24.000000Z"
id: 2
service_id: 1
state_image: "202209101955Screenshot (303).png"
state_text_ar: "agaga"
state_text_en: "afgagfa"
state_title_ar: "nice"
state_title_en: "idaljflia"
state_title_secondary_ar: "gagag"
state_title_secondary_en: "afaf"
updated_at: "2022-09-10T19:55:43.000000Z"
}
```

The problem:
when I call `state_image` to display the image
it not showing up.

react code :

```
React.createElement("div", {
      className: "slideContent",
      style: {
        backgroundImage: `url('${slide.state_image}')` }
 }
```

[image]

as you see in the background image (there is an image)
but nothing display in the screen

Comment: It seems there's a problem with the image path. Check if the image is in the root directory or a specific folder. If it's in a folder, make sure to include the folder name in the path. This should display the image correctly.

Answer (score 6):

To fetch image from API with React, we can use the fetch function.

For instance, we write:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const imageUrl = "https://i.imgur.com/fHyEMsl.jpg";

export default function App() {
  const [img, setImg] = useState();

  const fetchImage = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(imageUrl);
    const imageBlob = await res.blob();
    const imageObjectURL = URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob);
    setImg(imageObjectURL);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchImage();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <img src={img} alt="icons" />
    </>
  );
}
```

We call fetch with the imageUrl to make a GET request to it.

Then we call res.blob to convert the response object to a blob.

Next, we call URL.createObjectURL with the imageBlob to convert it to a URL string that we can set as the src attribute of the img element.

Finally, we call setImg with imageObjectURL so we can set img as the value of src to display it.

Conclusion
To fetch image from API with React, we can use the fetch function.

Comment: i did all that but i didn't share it

Comment: can you add your fetch funtion

Comment: const [slides, setSlides] = useState([])
  const id = Number(window.location.pathname.replace('/states/',''))
  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/state/show")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setSlides(data.filter((x) => x.service_id !== id)))
  
    },[])

Answer (score 0):

change to this:

```
React.createElement("div", {
      className: "slideContent",
      style: {
        backgroundImage: `url(${slide.state_image})` }
 }
```

Comment: i did it and noting happend